# How email sending works during user self registration in WSO2 IS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I checked the axi2.xml file and output-event-adapter.xml file. For email OTP, it is mentioned to configure email in axis2.xml file https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Configuring+Email+OTP.

But for user self-registration, it is asked to configure email in output-event adapter.xml file.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Self-Registration+and+Account+Confirmation.

Why there are two places for email configuration? How sending email notification works in user self-registration in WSO2 IS 5.7.0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2IS contains an email sending module with WSO2IS which is based on Axis2. This handles the email notifications in Email OTP.[1,2] Those configurations are stored in axis2.xml.But for instances like Ask Password Account Confirmation and user self-registration. WSO2 Is uses email event adapters[3]. These adapters get the configuration from output-event-adapter.xml.

[image: Current Email Sending architecture using email event adapters in wso2 is this is described in mail thread[4]]

In the above image global adapter configs are defined in the output-event-adapters.xml. And each adapter created per tenant holds a connection with the configured smtp server. When a tenant needs to send an email it publish the content to the relevant stream[5]

This stream creates the mapping to the relevant publisher using the stream wso2 is resolves the publisher. These publishers are defined in

**IS-HOME/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers**

these publishers specify the relevant adapter which has a connection with the SMTP server. It sends the email using that connection. This is how email sending handled in user self-registration. This has been further explained in[4].
As WSO2 IS has those two different mechanisms to handle notification you have to configure in two places for email OTP and account confirmation.As WSO2IS deprecating the Axis2 Based notification model.

**if you enabled the property**

```
<Parameter name="useEventHandlerBasedEmailSender">true</Parameter>
```

As per the documentation[6]. **You can use the configurations in the output-event-adapter.xml for email otp.** [7] But this supports after **identity server 5.8.0**.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHl6p.jpg). https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-email-otp/blob/f6ebf84f35d9da526077a0bfe220665e71baa7ec/component/authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/authenticator/emailotp/EmailOTPAuthenticator.java#L1708

[2]. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/34bb9053787020dbc901d17d7ee4290f075e6542/components/identity-mgt/org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/mgt/mail/DefaultEmailSendingModule.java#L73

[3]. https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/blob/5.2.x/components/event-publisher/event-output-adapters/org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.email/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/event/output/adapter/email/EmailEventAdapter.java

[4]. http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2019-September/032587.html

[5].https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-event-handler-notification/blob/master/components/event-handler-notification/org.wso2.carbon.identity.event.handler.notification/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/event/handler/notification/DefaultNotificationHandler.java#L284

[6]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Email+OTP

[7]. https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-email-otp/pull/26/files#diff-868475e354da25fd06fae3b3a9ebe6e5R272